# Is there an AES library for clojure?

Tags: encryption, clojure

Is there an AES encryption library for clojure? should I use a java libray available through maven or clojars? Thank your for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a perhaps more idiomatic example using the available java crypto libraries. `encrypt` and `decrypt` here each simply take input text and the encryption key, both as Strings.

```
(import (javax.crypto Cipher KeyGenerator SecretKey)
        (javax.crypto.spec SecretKeySpec)
        (java.security SecureRandom)
        (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64))

(defn bytes [s]
  (.getBytes s "UTF-8"))

(defn base64 [b]
  (Base64/encodeBase64String b))

(defn debase64 [s]
  (Base64/decodeBase64 (bytes s)))

(defn get-raw-key [seed]
  (let [keygen (KeyGenerator/getInstance "AES")
        sr (SecureRandom/getInstance "SHA1PRNG")]
    (.setSeed sr (bytes seed))
    (.init keygen 128 sr)
    (.. keygen generateKey getEncoded)))

(defn get-cipher [mode seed]
  (let [key-spec (SecretKeySpec. (get-raw-key seed) "AES")
        cipher (Cipher/getInstance "AES")]
    (.init cipher mode key-spec)
    cipher))

(defn encrypt [text key]
  (let [bytes (bytes text)
        cipher (get-cipher Cipher/ENCRYPT_MODE key)]
    (base64 (.doFinal cipher bytes))))

(defn decrypt [text key]
  (let [cipher (get-cipher Cipher/DECRYPT_MODE key)]
    (String. (.doFinal cipher (debase64 text)))))
```

Used suchwise:

```
(def key "secret key")
(def encrypted (encrypt "My Secret" key)) ;; => "YsuYVJK+Q6E36WjNBeZZdg=="
(decrypt encrypted key) ;; => "My Secret"
```

Comment: Someone packaged this up as https://github.com/clavoie/lock-key/blob/master/src/lock_key/core.clj

Answer (score 7):

Java's AES implementation is well-tested and included in the JDK…any Clojure library would likely use that impl itself.

See [Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption) for a decent discussion of the Java API.  Also, http://jyliao.blogspot.com/2010/08/exploring-java-aes-encryption-algorithm.html has an example of using the API from Clojure (though the code there isn't entirely idiomatic).

Answer (score 0):

[Tinklj](https://github.com/perkss/tinklj) is a great library that is wrapping Clojure around the [Google Tink Java API](https://github.com/google/tink). Google Tink supports all forms of encryption/decryption using streaming or deterministic. AES is supported AeadKeyTemplates.AES128_GCM.

It also offers MAC and Digital Signatures well worth checking out and getting involved.

For example:

```
(:require [tinklj.keys.keyset-handle :as keyset-handles])

(keyset-handles/generate-new :aes128-gcm)

(:require [tinklj.encryption.aead :refer [encrypt decrypt])

(encrypt aead (.getBytes data-to-encrypt) aad)
(decrypt aead encrypted aad)
```

Answer (score 0):

The encryption library [Clojure-AES](https://github.com/GriffinScribe-LLC/clojure-aes) is written entirely in Clojure. The only dependency is on Clojure 1.10 (as of Nov 2021), and it does not utilize any Java-based libraries. Feel free to try it out. It was coded directly from the [original NIST specification](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/197/final/documents/fips-197.pdf).

[image]